# Docker cannot run SQL Server container with volume

Tags: sql-server, docker

I tried to run a SQL Container using volumes but I get an error.

I'm using Windows 11 Home edition, with docker desktop.

I ran the following commands after installed docker desktop:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest

docker volume create sql_data

docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Password123.' -p 1433:1433 --name sqlserver1 -v sql_data:/var/opt/mssql/data -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
```

I got the error below:

```
2024-03-29 13:52:52 ERROR: BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (HRESULT 0x80070005)
2024-03-29 13:52:47 SQL Server 2022 will run as non-root by default.
2024-03-29 13:52:47 This container is running as user mssql.
2024-03-29 13:52:47 To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
2024-03-29 13:52:52 2024-03-29 13:52:52.50 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
2024-03-29 13:52:52.53 Server      ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf':  5(Access is denied.)
2024-03-29 13:52:52 
2024-03-29 13:52:52
```

Why is it failing?

If I use a path to the host machine the container keeps running instead of exiting with error:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Password123.' -p 1433:1433 --name sqlserver1 -v C:/Users/myuser/Documents/_docker:/var/opt/mssql/data -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
```

Comment: I was part way through writing an answer to this when it got closed. The way you've launched the container the `/var/opt/mssql/data` directory is owned by `root:root` so the SQL Server instance, running under `mssql:mssql`, cannot write anything there. You'll need to create a custom Dockerfile that includes `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest` `USER root` `RUN mkdir /var/opt/mssql/data ; chown mssql:mssql /var/opt/mssql/data` `USER mssql`, build it, and run from that.